# Should I use two arrays to check integer positions?

Tags: java, arrays

I have two sets of numbers, set A just is just the digits 0-9 and set B is a set sequence (e.g. 27645382196...).

My goal is to have set A loop constantly and have the user click it when the correct number in sequence comes up. So for example, when '2' is displayed, if it is clicked, it will stop looping (and just show '2') and a new loop will start right next to the first one. Then if '7' is clicked, that stops on 7 and a new loop starts next to it. If the wrong number is clicked, I want it to end and display just the correct digits that you managed to get.

My question is simply whether this should be achieved using two arrays or is there some more efficient method?

Many thanks.

Comment: is the sequence (set B) a fixed amount each time?

Comment: If it's just digits 0-9, why would you put them in a set? Just increase an integer with `a = ++a % 10` You can also keep the same loop and add your numbers to what you already have `b = b * 10 + a`

Comment: @chancea Yes, set B would have around 100 integers altogether.

Comment: @MichaëlBenjaminSaerens sorry I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Yeah then I am with @MichaëlBenjaminSaerens just use 1 array (for set B) and just constantly loop for set A.  There is no point in storing that in an array since you are going to have to index it using 0-9 anyway so just display the index value.

Comment: Unclear, what you mean by "correct" number? A shows i.e. 3 and B loops through random numbers? And when B shows the same number as A the user clicks on it?

Comment: @HarryStanley `a = ++a % 10` will generate the numbers `0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0-1-2-...` `b = b * 10 + a` will add the last selected number to the right. If you already have `245` and the user clicks on `7`, you'll get `2457`

Comment: @hamena314 I think it is pretty clear, the numbers 0-9 are looping and you have to click on the one that matches the next index in the set (set b).. so like first the user would try and click on 2, then 7, then 6... then like if they fail and don't hit 4 the game is over.

Comment: @chancea: Not clear, A could be looping and B shows the number the user has to wait for OR B is looping and A is showing the number the user has to wait for.

Comment: @hamena314 I don't get how that isn't clear.  A is looping......... they want to match it to the number in B..

Comment: @chancea: A shows 5 ... B shows 7, then 3, then 4, then 5 ... user clicks. A shows another number. Therefore A is looping also. To me it is not clear to which loop Harry Stanley is refering.

Comment: @hamena314 No B is not looping.  B is static.

Comment: @hamena314 A is looping 0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0-1-2-3-4... and B is a set order of digits.

Comment: Ah, did not see the comments 1 and 3. You are correct, B is not looping.

Comment: @MichaëlBenjaminSaerens & chancea thanks for the advice, you're right there's no point putting set A in an array.